# JXA keystroke does not work with numbers?

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation

I would like to trigger a keyboard shortcut using JXA.

This works:

```
system.keystroke('d', {
  using: ['control down', 'option down']
})
```

But this does not:

```
system.keystroke('3', {
  using: ['control down', 'option down']
})
```

The difference being the character ("3" instead of "d") used in the shortcut. Both work when manually triggering the shortcuts.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executive summary: You can use [keyCode codes](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes) instead of numbers to work around this issue. The number “20” is the code for the key that produces the number 3:

```
system = Application("System Events")
system.keyCode(20, {
    using: ['control down']
})
```

JXA does appear to successfully produce both a “d” and a “3”

```
system = Application("System Events")
system.keystroke('d')
system.keystroke('3')
```

It will also successfully produce both CMD-A and CMD-3. In Script Editor, this script will first select all (CMD-A), and then either hide or display the result window (CMD-3):

```
system = Application("System Events")
system.keystroke('a', {
    using: ['command down']
})
system.keystroke('3', {
    using: ['command down']
})
```

What it will not do is successfully handle the control key down with a number. I have verified that control-1, 2, and 3 will not switch desktops for me. If I change the shortcut for the second desktop from CTRL-2 to CTRL-A then the following will switch to the second desktop:

```
system = Application("System Events")
system.keystroke('a', {
    using: ['control down']
})
```

But this will *not* switch to the third desktop:

```
system = Application("System Events")
system.keystroke('3', {
    using: ['control down']
})
```

It beeps at me, and the result is “undefined”.

This is not a JXA problem. The same occurs in AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using control down
end tell
```

will switch to the second desktop.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "3" using control down
end tell
```

will beep and do nothing.

I do not know why this is happening. However, there does appear to be a workaround. You can use the [key code for the keys that produce numbers](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes) to get the desired behavior. For example, the key code for the key that produces the number 3 (or the pound/hash symbol) is 20. The line `key code 20 using {control down}` in AppleScript does switch to desktop 3:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 20 using {control down}
end tell
```

And the same is true of JXA:

```
system = Application("System Events")
system.keyCode(20, {
    using: ['control down']
})
```

This is on macOS Monterey 12.6.